# Highlight current link Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Thanks to a lot of help earlier this week, I was able to really get somewhere on this 'dynamic' page im trying to create. But now I'm running into the following problem:

I'm making a page that displays store info to the side of a list with all the stores. I was able to make dynamic content with this line:

```
document.getElementById('store').innerHTML = 'dynamic content';
```

But it would be great if one could also see on the list of cities (middle of the page) that this is the link they clicked. Hover is easy with some CSS, but I can't seem to make the links some sort of active.

I used this line:

```
document.getElementById('rood').style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

But this simply lights it up until you refresh the entire page. I want them to go back to normal black text once you click on a different store.

Here you will find my current code (content is in Dutch, but code should be readable just fine):
http://jsfiddle.net/T2Hv8/3/

And this will be the end result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPqyl.png (not allowed to post images directly)

I found a possible jQuery solution, but I can't get it to work. So if you could please post an example in your responses, thank you! Also, I'm trying to do everything pure javascript.

Comment: so you want the circles in the map to light up when you click on the cities on the side ? and stay selected until you click on another city on the side

Comment: Eventually, but that is not my question. I want the cities listed to be highlighted, they already work on :hover, but I need them to stay active when you click them, until you click a different city.

Comment: i can only provide a jquery solution if you are interested but i can also throw in the circle functionality as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally figured out what OP wants, at least I think:

Check it out fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/T2Hv8/10/

This is what you have to add in all ShowDiv function's (ShowDiv1, ShowDiv2, Showdiv3)

```
var spanID = obj.parentNode.id;
var newNode = document.getElementById(spanID);

var menus = document.getElementsByClassName("rood");
for (var i = menus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {   
        var elem = document.getElementById(menus[i].id);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
    }

newNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Comment: @Max V Z: I hope this helps.

Comment: That is indeed what I was looking for, thank you! Shame I made a messy example for you guys to work with. I'm trying of course to just make the text a different color. I can figure that out myself, but thank you very much for your help!

I also really need to figure out what this actually means.. since you know, I'll be using this on a clients website, haha.

Comment: No probelm. happy to help..Let me know if you want me to explain.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to use only javascript for the described functionality, you can do it like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/T2Hv8/9/

I have trid to do the complete example, but as i am running short of time, i tell you what i have done till now.

on each click function return the object i.e "this"

Then on the function showDiv1 i have implemented a loop that parse all element with class rood and changes its background color.

```
function showDiv1(obj) {
var menus = document.getElementsByClassName("rood");
for (var i = menus.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        //alert(menus[i].id);
        var elem = document.getElementById(menus[i].id);
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "#E9EEBF";
    }
document.getElementById('store').innerHTML = 'Vestiging 1 is nu open';
obj.style.backgroundColor = "red";    
}
```

PS this is only in the showDiv1 function for now, but can be copied to other two too.

Now why this is not working correctly, i have passed the obj of anchor on click, while looping through class rood i get obj of span with class "rood"

What you need to do is, add class and id to the anchor instead of span and then run the same code.

I am sure it will work fine.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
ids = ['id1', 'id2']
elems = [];

for(var i=0, len=ids.length; i<len; i++){
    elems.push(document.getElementById(ids[i])); 
    /* depend on what browsers you want to support you might prefere e.g. getElementsByClassName over above solution */
}

var select_one = function(e){
    for(var i=0, len=elems.length; i<len; i++){
        elems[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
    this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    /* changing classes would be better */
    return false;
}

for(var i=0, len=elems.length; i<len; i++){
    elems[i].onclick = select_one;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply add and remove an additional class `.rood_active` instead of relying on the `.rood:active` to stick. Since you've got the same class name across your links, you need to loop through them by your base `rood` class name and add the new active class to it.

Additional CSS class:

```
.rood_active {
    color: #f30089;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function selectActiveLink() {
    //get all your rood class elements; 'links' will be an array
    var links = document.getElementsByClassName('rood');
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
       var link = links[i];
       //reset all links to the base class 'rood'
       link.className = 'rood';
       link.addEventListener('click', function() {
           //this will add rood_active class (and change color) or only clicked span
           this.className = 'rood rood_active';
       });
    }
}

//then from within your other showDiv*() functions, call selectActiveLink()
function showDiv2() {

    //all the other showDiv* function stuff here

    selectActiveLink();
}
```